# Uncaught runtime errors: [u8;16]:: Expected input with 16 bytes (128 bits), found 21 bytes

Tags: storage, extrinsic, hash, query

I created a value `id` by this:

```
let encoded_payload = (owner.clone(), task_description.clone()).encode();
let id = frame_support::Hashable::blake2_128(&encoded_payload);// hashvalue of combined information
```

And then the problem is with the same value (type [u8;16]) I can make a query, but cannot pass it into extrinsic function.
Successful query with a hash value.
[image]
Call the extrinsic function and get an error
[image]
[image]

Here is my code of this function

```
#[pallet::weight(<T as pallet::Config>::WeightInfo::cause_error())]
pub fn taskTest(origin: OriginFor<T>, task_id: [u8; 16])-> DispatchResult {
        let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
        Ok(())
}
```

I tried to put the log in the extrinsic function but It did not even call into that.
I guess with the frontend, the size of hash value from input is not stable, and unable to call the function.
How to deal with this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Hope you are not passing a `Vec<u8>` where a `[u8; 16]` is expected. Writing a test in Rust first can also help to ensure that the extrinsic works as expected.